# How to return Boolean series meeting multiple conditions in Pandas using bracket notation for column names

Tags: pandas, series

I am trying to extract a series meeting multiple conditions in Pandas, i.e. using a boolean operator to filter the data, based on the [question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861902/how-to-return-boolean-series-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas), but I need to use the bracket column notation. (Python 3.7)

This works, and returns [index, Boolean]:

```
mySeries = data['myCol'] == 'A'
```

These both return errors:

```
mySeries = (data['rank'] == 'A' or data['rank'] == 'B')
mySeries = (data['rank'] == 'A' | data['rank'] == 'B')
```

The second one returns `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` The answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) seem to address this error for a dataframe, not a series. The second attempt returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]`

I am using bracket notation `df['rank']` instead of dot notation `df.rank` because in the dot notation, Pandas confuses the column name with the [rank method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @unutbu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas), this is the correct notation, the issue was that each condition needed to be in its own parentheses:

```
mySeries = (data['rank'] == 'A') | (data['rank'] == 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just do `isin`

```
mySeries = (data['rank'].isin(['A','B'])
```